# How can I reach base.php functions via my view files?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-3

I pass an array/object from my database to view file like this:

```
View::make('home.announcements')
    ->with('announcements', Announcements::all());
```

When it is passed to the view file, it contains some integers, like:

```
 $announcements[$k]->month //Output 05
```

I need to call a function inside `base.php` to convert 05 to "May", so I will get "May" result in the view.

```
 <span> {{ $this->convertMonthToString($announcements[$k]->month) }} </span>
 //Output: <span>May</span>
```

I know I can pass it directly with `->with` but that's not what I'm asking. I don't want to pass additional information using additional `->with`'s.

I want my views to handle those basic output functions.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create an function in your 'Announcements' model called:

```
public function get_fullmonth()
{
   return date('F', strtotime($this->get_attribute('month')));
}
```

Call in in your view as:

```
@foreach ($announcements as $item)
   <span>{{$item->fullmonth}}</span>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Is the model going to auto execute this function itself and extend the $announcements response to contain $announcements->fullmonth? Or, is $item->fullmonth is a manual call to the function?

Comment: Getters (functions starting `get_`) are automatically called when you try to access the property sharing the same name; in this case 'fullname'.